# pip installer seems not to write in the PATH in a Python server

Tags: python-2.7, server, pip

I tried to download Graphlab from Turi wit the following tutorial. I coded with their tools and tried to compute a Python script but it answered me an `ImportError`.

```
(gl-env)ubuntu@ip-172-hey-hey-hey:~/Eclipse-Stats$ source deactivate
discarding /home/ubuntu/anaconda2/envs/gl-env/bin from PATH
ubuntu@ip-172-hey-hey-hey:~/Eclipse-Stats$ unset PYTHONPATH
ubuntu@ip-172-hey-hey-hey:~/Eclipse-Stats$ python Main.py 
2017-07-27 14:56:00.520425
/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py:44: DeprecationWarning: This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in favor of the model_selection module into which all the refactored classes and functions are moved. Also note that the interface of the new CV iterators are different from that of this module. This module will be removed in 0.20.
  "This module will be removed in 0.20.", DeprecationWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import prediction
  File "/home/ubuntu/Eclipse-Stats/prediction.py", line 1, in <module>
    from graphlab.toolkits.recommender import ranking_factorization_recommender
ImportError: No module named graphlab.toolkits.recommender
```

Actually it cames often on the server when I tried to download with pip `numpy`, `scipy`, `sklearn`... Like we can see in [the following conversation (in Spanish)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62779/discussion-between-fjsevilla-and-marine1) between FJSevilla and the man of my team I'm working with.

Answer (score 0):

Two things: (1) check the version of your Python console and see if it matches or is higher than the compatibility with the packages. If you look at the depreciation message and read it through, you would understand what is going on a little more. (2) be careful of what you are importing and how you import them because your formatting might also be a syntactic all error. One thing you could do is find the package, manually download, unzip, then run the setup.py.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I get `$ python Python 2.7.12`, `(venv) ubuntu@ip-hey:~/Eclipse-Stats$ pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from /home/ubuntu/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)` and I don't know how to grab Anaconda2 version as far as it is a folder and it is said that *GraphLab Create installation requires a Python 2.7.x environment and pip version >= 7 and Anaconda2 v4.0.0 (64-bit)*. I think I have it all, and according to what I've understood from the Spanish conversation, the problem is deeper.

Comment: That is great! Hopefully it works out! If you get it worked out just accept my answer and up vote :)

Comment: No, I'm sorry, It doesn't. For instance with virtualen `ImportError: No module named psycopg2` , without I get the error shown in the question.

Comment: Then download `psycopg2`

Comment: Intentolo con el virtualenv pero tengo `$ pip install --user psycopg2
Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv.` Voy a intentar `pip install --user graphlab.toolkits.recommender` sin el.

Comment: The second sentence says it all. It seems pretty trivial at this point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150418/discussion-between-antoine-coppin-and-julian-rachman).